# Change NgbModal size after open

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that initially has a size, but I want the modal to change size when I change a certain value in the form.

I have this in my component .ts file that launch the modal

```
const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalFormComponent, { size : 'xl', scrollable: true });
```

If in the modal an information changes the modal size needs to change to lg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The open method of **NgbModal** class returns and NgbModalRef. The **_windowCmptRef.instance.size** property of NgbModalRef defines the size property of the currently opened Bootstrap Modal (NgbModal).

Now the question is how to access the NgbModalRef from the popup component. One way could be to define the reference object inside a service. Like this

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyserviceService {
  public modalRef: any;  //modalRef will be stored in this variable
  constructor() { }
}
```

Now open the **NgbModal** like this

```
this.myService.modalRef = this.ngbModalService.open(PopupComponent,  { size : 'xl', scrollable: true });
```

In the **PopupComponent**, you can change the size of the modal like this

```
this.myService.modalRef._windowCmptRef.instance.size='sm'; //the size property would be changed to small size.
```

Thanks.